# Performance issues rendering 100+ d3 line graphs

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to render approximately 150 d3 line graphs at a time, but it takes approximately 30 seconds to render all the graphs, and the browser is unusable during that time.

Data is stock prices, with each point on the graph defined by a price and a timestamp. Graphs looks similar to those found here: https://finviz.com/futures.ashx -- this page renders great, but they have 1/3 as many graphs to render and their data is just prices, no timestamps, which is what I'm assuming allows the page to render so quickly. For various reasons, I can't get rid of the timestamps with my data.

Code:

```
$('.d3_chart').each( function() {

  var data = JSON.parse($(this).attr('d3-plot-data'));

  var svg = d3.select(this),
      margin = {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0},
      width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
      g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var parseTime = d3.utcParse('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');

  var x = d3.scaleTime()
      .rangeRound([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .rangeRound([height, 0]);

  var line = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) { return x(parseTime(d[1])); })
      .y(function(d) { return y(d[0]); });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return parseTime(d[1]); }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[0]; }));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
      .select(".domain")
      .remove();

  g.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "white")
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", line);
});
```

Data:

```
[[145.23, "2017-05-26 13:30:19"], [146.24, "2017-05-26 13:31:46"], [146.76, "2017-05-26 13:33:05"], [146.72, "2017-05-26 13:33:05"], etc...]
```

Each graph contains approximately 500 prices.

This is my first time using d3, and I'm wondering if there's anything that I'm doing wrong that's slowing down rendering, or anything that I could change to speed up rendering, or if this is never going to work like this?

Comment: Why is your data stored in the dom? It seems wrong. Also, do your charts share the same dimensions/domains? If so, you can reuse the scales, instead of recalculating them every loop.

Comment: dom was the simplest way for testing. A separate JSON request would be an improvement but I don't think that would speed anything up? Yes the dimensions / domains would be similar enough that they could be reused, I'll definitely try that.

Comment: *"A separate JSON request would be an improvement but I don't think that would speed anything up"*... you're wrong, the improvement will be huge. Besides that, mixing D3 and jQuery is a terrible idea.

Comment: okay fair enough I'll try it, thanks!